# Extjs 4.0.7, Window + 2 children, child 1 gets all size

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
function ShowMsg(mensaje) {
  if (!msgWnd) {
    var okBtn = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
      text    : 'Aceptar',
      id      : 'okBtn',
      icon    : 'images/ok.png',
      height  : 25,
      scope   : this,
      handler : function() {
        ShowMsg('');
      }
    });

    msgWnd = new Ext.Window({
      layout:'fit',
      id: 'msgWindow',
      title: 'DigiDoc',
      width: 300,
      height: 180,
      closable: false,
      resizable: true,
      autoScroll: true,
      plain: true,
      border: false,
      items: [
        {
          html: '<div>' + mensaje + '</div>',
          id: 'myMsgText',
          autoHeight: false,
          autoWidth: false
        },
        okBtn
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

This should show a Message and a ACCEPT button, but the MESSAGE size is fitting ALL the space of the window, leaving the ACCEPT button out of visual. Shouldn't ExtJS make this element size the same of the Window's one minus the other elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html:

> **Ext.layout.container.Fit**
>
> A very simple layout that simply fills the
>   container with a **single panel**. This is usually the best default layout
>   choice when you have no other specific layout requirements.

What are you trying to achieve? If it's simply to show a message box to alert the user of something, try [Ext.Msg](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox) instead. [Here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html) are several examples of usage. In any other case, you might want to be using the vbox layout instead.

Comment: So that means that only one element should be in items[] of the element having layout: fit? Currently I am putting 2 elements, one text, and one button

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, I insist that unless your message is expected to be really huge, I'd really use the Ext.Msg class, which is really about showing a message with a button (you can customize the button if you like...)

Comment: Yes thanks, I will use the Ext.Msg. I don't know why the previous guy did that way. I am maintaining the code